# the value of $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x^2+1) \ln(x^2+1)-\sin(x^2)}{x\sin(x^2)}$

Tags: limits

I want to compute this limit
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x^2+1) \ln(x^2+1)-\sin(x^2)}{x\sin(x^2)}.$$
I tried to apply Hopital rule, but I cannot compute it.

Comment: Try without L'Hôpital.

Answer (score 1):

Just to suggest another way: $\ln(1+x^2)=x^2-\frac{x^4}2+O(x^6)$ and $\sin(x^2)=x^2+O(x^6)$, so the numerator behaves like $(x^2+1)(x^2-\frac{x^4}2)-x^2\sim\frac{x^4}2$. The denominator on the other hand behaves like $x^3$.

---

**Proof that the limit is $0$.**

1. By simple study of functions, we check that $\lvert\ln(x^2+1)-x^2\rvert\le\frac{x^4}2$ and $\lvert\sin(x^2)-x^2\rvert\le\frac{x^6}6$.
2. Then we can bound the numerator as
   \begin{align*}
   \Bigl|(x^2+1)\ln(x^2+1)-\sin(x^2)\Bigr|&\le x^2\ln(x^2+1)+\lvert\ln(x^2+1)-x^2\rvert+|x^2-\sin(x^2)|\\
   &\le x^4+\frac{x^6}2+\frac{x^4}2+\frac{x^6}2\\
   &=\frac32x^4+x^6.
   \end{align*}
3. Now
   $$\left\lvert\frac{(x^2+1)\ln(x^2+1)-\sin(x^2)}{x\sin(x^2)}\right\rvert
   \le\frac{\frac32x^2+x^4}{|x|}\cdot\frac{x^2}{\lvert\sin(x^2)\rvert}
   =\left(\frac32|x|+|x|^3\right)\left\lvert\frac{x^2}{\sin(x^2)}\right\rvert.$$

Comment: So the limit is $0$? Thanks

Comment: @Student Yes, more precisely, it goes to $0$ just like $\frac12x$ goes to $0$.

Comment: I agree to you thanks. So the other answers are not correct I think

Comment: Indeed, they are incorrect. You can check with [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5B%28%28x%5E2%2B1%29*Log%5Bx%5E2%2B1%5D-Sin%5Bx%5E2%5D%29%2F%28x*Sin%5Bx%5E2%5D%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D).

Comment: yes. I'm sure your proof is correct but I hope to find another way. Since my students does not know this technique

Comment: @Student Well you could use L'Hôpital… but you need to differentiate thrice to clear the indeterminate form.

Comment: yes i know, it is so long

Comment: @Student I updated my answer to include an elementary argument.

Answer (score 0):

Various tricks can simplify the limit. Multiply by $\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}$ which has a limit of one to reduce to
$$\frac{(x^2+1) \ln(x^2+1)-\sin(x^2)}{x^3}.$$Add $$\frac{\sin x^2 -x^2}{x^3}$$ to reduce to

$$\frac{(x^2+1) \ln(x^2+1)-x^2}{x^3}.$$Now break into pieces,
$$\frac{\ln(x^2+1)-1}{x}+\frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{x^3}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. In this case the limit is infinite. But I think it is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Make life easier writing
$$\frac{(x^2+1) \ln(x^2+1)-\sin(x^2)}{x\sin(x^2)}=x\frac{(x^2+1) \ln(x^2+1)-\sin(x^2)}{x^2\sin(x^2)}$$ Now, let $t=x^2$ to make
$$\frac{(x^2+1) \ln(x^2+1)-\sin(x^2)}{x^2\sin(x^2)}=\frac{(t+1) \ln(t+1)-\sin(t)}{t\sin(t)}$$ Using equivalent $\ln(t+1)\sim t$ and $\sin(t)\sim t$
$$\frac{(t+1) \ln(t+1)-\sin(t)}{t\sin(t)}\sim \frac{(t+1)t-t }{t^2 }=1$$

So, the expression is "similar" to $x$.

Comment: Thanks but the equivalence does not work with difference. So the last equation is not clear

Comment: @Student. Do not foget to multiply the last result by $x$. So $x \times 1 \to 0$

Comment: My ptoblem is here Professor $$\frac{(t+1) \ln(t+1)-\sin(t)}{t\sin(t)}\sim \frac{(t+1)t-t }{t^2 }=1$$The argument is not clear since the equivalence does not work with sum.

Comment: @Student. Where is the problem ?

Comment: The problem is here Professor $(t+1) \ln(t+1)-\sin(t)\sim (t+1)t-t$. It us clear that $(t+1) \ln(t+1)\sim (t+1)t$ and $\sin(t)\sim t$. But why $(t+1) \ln(t+1)-\sin(t)\sim (t+1)t-t$?